# Implementing Tabu Search in R

Tags: r, search, machine-learning, classification, tabu-search

I am trying to implement Tabu Search on a classification dataset namely Indian patients liver disease available in the UCI repository on https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ILPD+(Indian+Liver+Patient+Dataset) but facing issues.
Following is the code I've used

```
NF <- 10
NTR <- 193
NTE <- 193
library(class) 
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(party)
library(nnet)
ILPD <- read.csv("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Codes and Datasets/ILPD.csv")
nrow(ILPD)  
set.seed(9850)
gp<-runif(nrow(ILPD))
ILPD<-ILPD[order(gp),]
idx <- createDataPartition(y = ILPD$Class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train<-ILPD[idx,]
test<-ILPD[-idx,]
ver<-test[,11]
evaluate <- function(th){ 
if (sum(th) == 0)return(0)             
model <- svm(train[ ,th==1], train[,11] , gamma = 0.1, kernel ="sigmoid", na.action = na.omit)
pred <- predict(model, test[ ,th==1])
csRate <- sum(pred == ver)/NTE 
penalty <- (NF - sum(th))/NF 
return(csRate + penalty)
}  
library(tabuSearch)
res <- tabuSearch(size = NF, iters = 2, objFunc = evaluate, config =     matrix(1,1,NF), listSize = 5, nRestarts = 4) 
plot(res)
plot(res, "tracePlot")
summary(res, verbose = TRUE)
```

Error:

```
Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
Called from: svm.default(train[, th == 1], train[, 11], gamma = 0.1, kernel = "sigmoid", na.action = na.omit)
```

Some part of the data

```
structure(list(age = c(55L, 48L, 14L, 17L, 40L, 37L), gender = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TB = c(0.9, 2.4, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7), DB = c(0.2, 
1.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2), Alkphos = c(116L, 554L, 310L, 224L, 
293L, 235L), SGPT = c(36L, 141L, 21L, 36L, 232L, 96L), sgot = c(16L, 
73L, 16L, 45L, 245L, 54L), TP = c(6.2, 7.5, 8.1, 6.9, 6.8, 9.5
), ALB = c(3.2, 3.6, 4.2, 4.2, 3.1, 4.9), AG = c(1, 0.9, 1, 1.55, 
0.8, 1), Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("One", 
"Two"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "gender", "TB", 
"DB", "Alkphos", "SGPT", "sgot", "TP", "ALB", "AG", "Class"), row.names =    c(216L, 
405L, 316L, 103L, 20L, 268L), class = "data.frame")
```

If anyone could help me with it

Comment: You'll probably receive more (and more useful) help if you provide a minimal reproducable example. Yours is neither minimal, nor reproducable without us exerting signfiicant effort (e.g. downloading data, etc). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Error says there is NA inside if(), e.g.: `if(NA){"it is NA"} else {"it is not NA"}`

Comment: @coffeinjunky Did so by adding dput of the head of the dataset.

Comment: Anything wrong with this answer? Have you had a look?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to see how tabu worked anyway so seemed a good place to start.

Basically you need to test your code better, `evaluate` just did not work. It is easy to test by hand by creating values of `th` and then calling `evaluate` on them.

Also use high level comments to organize your code and keep track of what you are doing, especially when posting to SO for help so as to save us time figuring out what you intend.

Not sure if these results are good, the amount of data is so minimal it is hard to tell.

Anyway here is the changed code:

```
NF <- 10
NTR <- 193
NTE <- 193
library(class)
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(party)
library(nnet)

ILPD1 <- structure(
 list(
    age = c(55L,48L,14L,17L,40L,37L),
    gender = c(0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L),
    TB = c(0.9,2.4,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.7),
    DB = c(0.2,1.1,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2),
    Alkphos = c(116L,554L,310L,224L,293L,235L),
    SGPT = c(36L,141L,21L,36L,232L,96L),
    sgot = c(16L,73L,16L,45L,245L,54L),
    TP = c(6.2,7.5,8.1,6.9,6.8,9.5),
    ALB = c(3.2,3.6,4.2,4.2,3.1,4.9),
    AG = c(1,0.9,1,1.55,0.8,1),
    Class = structure(c(2L,1L,2L,1L,1L,1L),
    .Label = c("One","Two"),
    class = "factor")
   ),
   .Names = c("age","gender","TB","DB","Alkphos",
               "SGPT","sgot","TP","ALB","AG","Class"),
   row.names = c(216L,405L,316L,103L,20L,268L),
   class = "data.frame"
)

ILPD <- ILPD1
#ILPD <- read.csv("ILPD.csv")
nrow(ILPD)

set.seed(9850)

# setup test and training data
gp <- runif(nrow(ILPD))
ILPD <- ILPD[order(gp),]
idx <- createDataPartition(y = ILPD$Class,p = 0.7,list = FALSE)
train <- ILPD[idx,]
test <- ILPD[ - idx,]
ver <- test[,11]

evaluate <- function(th) {
    # evaluate the tabu for a value of th
    # tabuSearch will use this function to evaluate points in its search space
    #

    # if everything is turned off just return zero as we are not interested
    if(sum(th) == 0)  return(0)

    # we just want to train our svm on the columns for which th==1
    svmtrn <- train[,th==1]

    # but we need to have the Class varible as our label
    if (is.null(trn$Class)) return(0)

    # Train up an svm now
    #  Note that the first argument is the forumula we are training
    model <- svm(Class~.,svmtrn,gamma = 0.1,kernel = "sigmoid",na.action = na.omit)

    pred <- predict(model,test)

    # now evaluate how well our prediction worked
    csRate <- sum(pred == ver) / NTE
    penalty <- (NF - sum(th)) / NF
    return(csRate + penalty)
}

library(tabuSearch)
evaluate(matrix(1,1,NF))
res <- tabuSearch(size = NF,iters = 2,objFunc = evaluate,
                  config = matrix(1,1,NF),listSize = 5,nRestarts = 4)
plot(res)
plot(res,"tracePlot")
summary(res,verbose = TRUE)
```

Here are the output results:

> ```
> [1] 6
> [1] 0.005181347
> Tabu Settings
>   Type                                       = binary configuration
>   No of algorithm repeats                    = 1
>   No of iterations at each prelim search     = 2
>   Total no of iterations                     = 12
>   No of unique best configurations           = 8
>   Tabu list size                             = 5
>   Configuration length                       = 10
>   No of neighbours visited at each iteration = 10
> Results:
>   Highest value of objective fn    = 0.70518
>   Occurs # of times                = 1
>   Optimum number of variables      = 3
> Optimum configuration: 
>  [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
> ```

And here is your plot:

[image]